# Microsoft Server 2008 R2 not writing to text file from task scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, text, nlog

I have done some extensive searching over the net however I cannot seem to find a concrete solution to the problem I am facing. The closest was this article ... but still no solution :( [scheduled task run .exe problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073508/scheduled-task-run-exe-problem)

Basically the environment is a Windows Server 2008 R2 running a C# console application. When I run the console application manually a text file (using NLog) is created and appended, however when I run the console from windows scheduler using the Domain Administrator account, the application runs (as I deciphered from Event Viewer logs) but the text file is not created / appended. I also tried changing the account that runs the scheduled task (from Domain Administrator to Local Administrator account) but the problem is still persisting.

Cannot think of anything else I can do. Any fresh ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: where do you write the file ? Are you sure the application can write in this path in this particular context (scheduled task) ?

Comment: also, can you post the code for writing the file. make sure you are specyfying the full path to the NLog as running as task means the working directory will be different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

thought id post as an answer as it's easier to put the code in:

make sure you specify the full path to the NLog:

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),"NLog.txt");
```

when running as a scheduled task the working directory of your application can be different, such as running under system means the working directory is C:\Windows\System32.

this could be your issue.